# repeat twice each couple of strings in a for cycle

Tags: bash, numbering

I need to pass to pdftk, a list of arguments constituted by strings repeated twice like:

`A1-2 B1-2 A3-4 B3-4 A5-6 B5-6...` and so on...

I managed to achieve this with this workaround

```sh
for ((x=1, y=2;x>=18, y<=18;x++, y++)); do echo "A$x-$y B$x-$y "; done| awk 'NR %2==1 {print $1, $2} ' | tr '\n' ' '
```

that gives:

**A1-2 B1-2 A3-4 B3-4 A5-6 B5-6 A7-8 B7-8 A9-10 B9-10 A11-12 B11-12 A13-14 B13-14 A15-16 B15-16 A17-18 B17-18**

but I'm unsatisfied, and I'm looking for a proper , more elegant and better way to perform this task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for ((x=1; x<=18; x+=2)); do echo -n "A$x-$((x+1)) B$x-$((x+1)) "; done
```

Comment: You can even use 2 variables, as in C: `for (( x=1, y=2; x<=18; x+=2, y+=2 )); do printf "A%d-%d B%d-%d " $x $y $x $y; done`

Answer (score 5):

or even pure awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for (i=1; i<19; i+=2) printf "A"i"-"i+1 " B"i"-"i+1" "}'
```

Answer (score 1):

With just bash:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat $(for ((x=1; x<18; x+=2)); do echo {A,B}$x-$((x+1)); done) output output.pdf
```

With GNU utilities (Linux or Cygwin):

```
pdftk input.pdf cat $(seq 1 2 17 | awk '{$1 = $1 "-" ($1+1); print "A" $1; print "B" $1}') output output.pdf
```

With Perl:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat $(perl -e 'print map {"A$_ B$_ "} map {(2*$_-1) . "-" . (2*$_)} (1..9)') output output.pdf
```

Comment: +1 for offering valuable alternative one-liners. Maybe it would be worth considering to add xargs in order to not have **too many arguments** error, if number of strings becomes very big (100 or 200 or more)